# Starting one task after finishing another

Tags: php, nginx, vbscript, cmd

In a .vbs i have something like

```
   Dim sh
   Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   'run conf
   sh.run "cmd /K php -c php.ini -f some_path\runer\run.php & pause",0,false
   'Navigate to the nginx folder to run server
    sh.run "cmd /K start nginx & exit", 0, false
    Set sh = Nothing
```

this code is working fine.

But i want to execute `sh.run "cmd /K start nginx & exit", 0, false` this after completely finishing execution of `sh.run "cmd /K php -c php.ini -f some_path\runer\run.php & pause",0,false` this command, that means, after finishing the task of `run.php` i want to `run nginx`. please answer me if it is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this,

```
Dim sh
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'run conf
sh.run "cmd /K php -c php.ini -f some_path\runer\run.php & exit",1,true
'Navigate to the nginx folder to run server
sh.run "cmd /K start nginx & exit", 0, false
Set sh = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation for your method. You are telling it not to wait. Some reason it didn't occur to you to read the documentation?

Runs a program in a new process.

```
object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])
```

Arguments
object 
WshShell object.

strCommand 
String value indicating the command line you want to run. You must include any parameters you want to pass to the executable file.

intWindowStyle 
Optional. Integer value indicating the appearance of the program's window. Note that not all programs make use of this information.

bWaitOnReturn 
Optional. Boolean value indicating whether the script should wait for the program to finish executing before continuing to the next statement in your script. If set to true, script execution halts until the program finishes, and Run returns any error code returned by the program. If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code).

Remarks
The Run method returns an integer. The Run method starts a program running in a new Windows process. You can have your script wait for the program to finish execution before continuing. This allows you to run scripts and programs synchronously. Environment variables within the argument strCommand are automatically expanded. If a file type has been properly registered to a particular program, calling run on a file of that type executes the program. For example, if Word is installed on your computer system, calling Run on a *.doc file starts Word and loads the document. The following table lists the available settings for intWindowStyle.

```
intWindowStyle  Description  
0
 Hides the window and activates another window.

1
 Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when displaying the window for the first time.

2
 Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window. 

3
 Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window. 

4
 Displays a window in its most recent size and position. The active window remains active.

5
 Activates the window and displays it in its current size and position.

6
 Minimizes the specified window and activates the next top-level window in the Z order.

7
 Displays the window as a minimized window. The active window remains active.

8
 Displays the window in its current state. The active window remains active.

9
 Activates and displays the window. If the window is minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring a minimized window.

10
 Sets the show-state based on the state of the program that started the application.
```

Example 1
The following VBScript code opens a copy of the currently running script with Notepad.

Copy Code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName
```

The following VBScript code does the same thing, except it specifies the window type, waits for Notepad to be shut down by the user, and saves the error code returned from Notepad when it is shut down.

Copy Code

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Return = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, true)
```

Example 2
The following VBScript code opens a command window, changes to the path to C:\ , and executes the DIR command.

Copy Code

```
Dim oShell

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")

oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"

Set oShell = Nothing
```

Applies To:

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  sh.run "cmd /K php -c php.ini -f some_path\runer\run.php & exit",1,true
```

Answer (score 1):

For any query you can use:

```
Dim sh
Set sh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sh.run "cmd /K a.exe & exit",1,true
Set sh = Nothing
```

I think this will help you.